# System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

My code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sql.Open();

        string id = textBox1.Text;
        string cadena = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id=" + id;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cadena, sql);

        int cant;
        cant = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (cant == 1)
        {
            label4.Text = "";
            label5.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha eliminado");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No existe un artículo con el código ingresado");

        sql.Close();
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }
```

But is already declared the close connection.

Comment: Bad practices have the habit to hit your code in strange ways. Do not keep a global connection object. Just use one locally, create it with the connectionstring loaded from your config, use it and then destroy. The using statement is the one to look for.

Comment: There is a SQL injection attack vector in the code, parameterize your query.

Comment: maybe use using (....), so it will always close

Answer (score 0):

Check your 
    sql.Close();
It looks to me it is included in the else block.

```
    int cant;
   cant = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql.Close(); //Move it here.
    if (cant == 1)
    {
        label4.Text = "";
        label5.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Se ha eliminado");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No existe un artículo con el código ingresado");
    }
    button2.Enabled = false;
```

You should close your connections after using them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it right from the start, too many sins are commited:

```
 //DONE: extract business logics, do not mix it with UI
 private bool DropContact(string id) {
   //DONE: do not share single connection, but create when you want it
   //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
     con.Open();

     //DONE: make sql readable
     //DONE: make sql parametrized
     string cadena = 
       @"DELETE 
           FROM contacts 
          WHERE id = @prm_id";

     //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cadena, con)) {
       //TODO: explict parameter type (int/string?) is a better then inplicit AddWithValue
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_id", id);

       return command.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1;
     }
   } 
 }
 ...
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (DropContact(textBox1.Text)) {
     label4.Text = "";
     label5.Text = "";
     MessageBox.Show("Se ha eliminado");
   }
   else {
     MessageBox.Show("No existe un artículo con el código ingresado");
   }

   button2.Enabled = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sharing the `sql` object around. I think the problem is that you opened a connection somewhere else but never closed it. The end result is that you get to this function and it breaks when you call this line:

```
sql.Open();
```

Check your code and find the place where you did not correctly close the connection.

Also, it's preferable NOT to share connection objects like this but rather create a new one every time.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code:
1) You can get an exception before connection closing.
To avoid that use `using` statement it's very comfortable because it's have catching exceptions support or you can use try-catch-finally statement and close connection in `finally` block.
2) Initialize SqlConnection object only per connection (please check example). Don't share  it between separate operations because it may causing problem that you meant.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   con.Open();
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("your query", con))
   {
    // output processing
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to check the connection state before re-open (in case using it globally as you did). by the way (don't make the connection public or open for long time)

```
if (sql != null && sql.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    sql.Open();
```

just add this if condition before try opening the connection. but better to enhance your strategy.